# Are BGA components sold already with soldering balls on?

Tags: components, bga

I never bought a BGA component and I'm wondering if they arrived already with the soldering ball on it, so the component is ready for the placement and the heating. Maybe it'a a choice of the manufacturer or maybe is a standard.

Comment: Why would a supplier sell a ball-grid-array without a ball?

Comment: If there are no balls underneath, a package is called LGA (land grid array).

Comment: How is this not directly answered in the datasheet?  Surely that would show dimensions of any balls.  Also, what exactly do you think the term *ball grid array* refers to if there are no balls.

Comment: Guys relax! I never seen one BGA and I thought that the balls were applied during the placement process. Maybe I was confused by some video on web that do a purely re-balling process. I thought also that the possibility of the "non-balled" component could arise from some mechanical reason. Why then the manufacturer don't place a little solder on component's pin (QFP for example) to facilitate the soldering (little enough to don't create too space between chip and the board)? These are two different cases, I know, but why not? And why the LDAs don't have already solder on it?

Comment: Sometimes the balls are removed and the package is reballed, for example to replace Pb-free with Pb balls (or for repairs).

Answer (score 4):

Yes they arrive with solder balls already attached. It is difficult to apply your own solder, and the process of replacing them is called re-balling. It requires a stencil to accurately apply the paste. For various reasons, reballing likely to create voids inside the ball (especially lead free).

Factory balling is preferred as this is done in a tightly controlled atmosphere with extreme cleanliness, suitable flux and precision stencils.

FYI IPC states the maximum allowable voiding is 25%, which would look like a bubble inside the ball on an X-ray.

Comment: You can actually buy the balls pre-formed and not have to try to create them from paste and surface tension.

Comment: I'd never heard of that until just now!